# How to create a structure like skype support page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can i create a structure like Skype support page (https://support.skype.com/en/) with use of categories in wordpress

Display 1st level categories as titles like "Calling", "Video Calling, "Messaging", etc. (without links) and then display all sub categories of each 1st level category under it as a list with links to their corresponding archive pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need nothing more than [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) (making use of its options) to do that. Just one nested loop (get the top level categories, then the subcategories), or a custom walker to render the whole tree.